# configure redis auth on sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I think I am missing something since I couldn't find in the docs how to write the username and password for the redis instance to use with sidekiq..

Is there a way to do this? Or is it through ENV vars?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sidekiq passes unrecognized redis options directly to the Redis driver:

```
config.redis = { password: 'bar' }
```

And redis does not have the concept of users so there's only password.

Comment: I needed to do this in both `Sidekiq.configure_server` & `Sidekiq.configure_client` blocks http://stackoverflow.com/a/34208337/161815

Comment: `config` is a reference to the `Rails.application.configuration` object, yes?

Comment: @mecampbellsoup Nope. The Sidekiq config object.