# Rails, Sidekiq - Redis NOAUTH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redis, sidekiq

I use sidekiq on rails for sending out emails. I've added a password for the redis server but cant seem to get it right because I get an error

```
D, [2015-12-10T16:49:52.714279 #10497] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
I, [2015-12-10T16:49:52.720380 #10497]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 5bce215c-7649-4774-8c6e-d29e743cf25e) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: "MessageMailer", "new_message", "deliver_now", gid://customer-app/Message/18
I, [2015-12-10T16:49:52.723400 #10497]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
F, [2015-12-10T16:49:52.726204 #10497] FATAL -- :
Redis::CommandError (NOAUTH Authentication required.):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:37:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:35:in `create'
```

My sidekiq log shows it should be ok?

```
2015-12-10T16:49:39.220Z 10448 TID-ows27pimw INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.5.3 with redis options {:url=>"redis://localhost:6379/0", :password=>"REDACTED", :namespace=>"sidekiq"}
2015-12-10T16:49:40.916Z 10448 TID-ows27pimw INFO: Running in ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
```

This is my sidekiq.rb inside initializers

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :url => "redis://#{}localhost:6379/0", password: ENV["REDIS_PASSWORD"], :namespace => "sidekiq" }
end
```

Comment: If you log/puts ENV["REDIS_PASSWORD"] does it have the correct value?

Comment: @RichardAE I started rails console and it output the correct value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to configure Redis in both server and client blocks, as explained in the [Using Redis wiki page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis).

Comment: Thanks - using both of these did the trick like you say: Sidekiq.configure_client ... and ... Sidekiq.configure_server